# How can mutt indicate the presence of all attachments?

Tags: mutt

### Indicating the presence of attachments

In `mutt`, I can tell an email has an attachment because it is indicated in the email's display itself:

```
[-- Attachment #1 --]
[-- Type: text/plain, Encoding: quoted-printable, Size: 0.3K --]

body text here

[-- Attachment #2: IMG_1234.JPG --]
[-- Type: image/jpeg, Encoding: base64, Size: 682K --]

[-- image/jpeg is unsupported (use 'v' to view this part) --]
```

I've also created a colour scheme to highlight these entries in the index (although I am [forced](https://superuser.com/questions/426220/change-mutt-indicator-color-when-hovering-a-new-message) to use the arrow cursor). In my `muttrc`:

```
color index green color231 "~X 1-"
```

### Doesn't always work

However, sometimes emails with attachments are not indicated in the email display, nor highlighted in the index. These emails are structured as follows, after pressing `v`:

```
->   I     1 <no description>                          [multipa/alternativ, 7bit, 12M]
     I     2 ├─><no description>                    [text/plain, 7bit, us-ascii, 0.1K]
     I     3 └─><no description>                          [multipa/related, 7bit, 12M]
     I     4   ├─><no description>                 [text/html, quoted, us-ascii, 1.4K]
     I     5   ├─>IMG_1234.jpeg                             [image/jpeg, base64, 3.9M]
     I     6   ├─>IMG_1235.jpeg                             [image/jpeg, base64, 1.4M]
     I     7   ├─>IMG_1236.jpeg                             [image/jpeg, base64, 3.0M]
     I     8   └─>IMG_1237.jpeg                             [image/jpeg, base64, 4.4M]
```

This example was created in Apple Mail. Possibly this is a bug with this client. Nevertheless, how can I make `mutt` indicate the presence of attachments? I've missed some attachments as a consequence.

### What I've tried

One possible option that I explored was to highlight all emails above some arbitrary size, but this obviously doesn't work in all cases (and doesn't indicate the attachments in the email display itself).

```
color index green color231 "~z 30K-"
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than colours I just use the `index_format` string to show the presence of attachments, like this:

`set index_format = "[%Z][%?X?A& ?]  %D  %-20.20F  %s %g"`

The `%?X?A& ?` is a ternary which says *if* the email has nonzero attachments *then* show the character "A", *else* show " ". You could actually show the number of attachments but I generally just care if there are any, or none.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, it still fails in the above example, which is the main thrust of my question.

Comment: Oh interesting, never encountered that problem but sounds like something that should be handled... prob have to dig into how mutt figures out what an "attachment" is.

Comment: Does not seem to work for me either: there is nothing shown for a message with structure similar to what is pointed out in the question.